# Postgresql 11 - View Filter as Function Parameter

Tags: postgresql

I have a function that use a partitioned list of tables.
To make it simple:

```
CREATE FUNCTION "test_func_params"(
    "_ts_from" TIMESTAMP,
    "_ts_to" TIMESTAMP
)
RETURNS UNKNOWN
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
$$ 
SELECT date_from, date_to, name FROM master_table where date_from <= $1 and date_to >= $2;
$$
```

Now I can do a query as:

```
select * from test_func_params(date_from , date_to) where name = "foo";
```

Unfortunally my external software cant do select on functions but only on table/views.

I can make a view on this function but what I want is to be able to filter the view passing parameter to function.

```
CREATE VIEW "view_test" as  SELECT * FROM test_func_params() as inner_table;
```

I want to be able to filter the view like:

```
SELECT * FROM view_test WHERE test_func_params._ts_from = "....." and inner_table.name = "foo";
```

The "_ts_from" filter is not acting on the RESULT table of function but directly as the PARAMETER of function THAT generate the table.

Is this possible?

Comment: That `CREATE FUNCTION` statement is syntactically incorrect. If your tool cannot use a function, why do you want to force it to use a function?

Comment: That code of that function was only an example. My Tool (Microsoft Power BI) cant access to a function. I need a function, instead of a table/view, because I have to make a pivot (crosstab) on TimeStamp Partitioned tables that is specified in that function (in my example is ommitted because is not the point of the question WHY I need it).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I only asked "why" to fathom if there could be a workaround. I guess there is no solution for you then: you need functions, but you are using a tool that cannot call functions.